# Cannot connect to localhost MySQL - mysql.sock error - ERROR 2002 (HY000)

Tags: php, mysql, homebrew

I'm using a brew php mysql config for my localhost and after trying to switch from php71 to php56, I am now unable to connect to my localhost and get this error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

My services running:

[image]

I am researching this for quite some time now and I can't seem to be able to fix it. Please can someone help me? I'm going crazy.

Comment: Installing multiple versions of PHP can lead to random errors, at least that's my experience.

Comment: check your file with configured with correct socket value?

Comment: @suresh How so? I've looked through everything I can think of.

Comment: @Michael I haven't got much choice unfortunately on that one!

Comment: where is mysql.sock file resides. check the same is configured in mysql configuration file?

Comment: If you are on localhost, you might be able to move one PHP version to a virtual machine.

Comment: @suresh I don't have a mysql.sock file. It used to work yesterday before I restarted my machine

Comment: Everything was working find until I use this gist to be able to switch versions of php >> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rhukster/f4c04f1bf59e0b74e335ee5d186a98e2/raw

Comment: Even not working when I try to do :

`mysql -u root -p`
I get:
`ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)`

Comment: Please can someone help me? I'm losing the will to live with this.